# Awk last field string substitution

Tags: awk, gsub

I am trying to get the last filed using string substiution of following output using awk -

```
ps -ef |grep -i "[o]cssd.bin"
```

Output:

```
grid     47275     1  1 Sep23 ?        17:49:39 /opt/grid/12.1/bin/ocssd.bin
```

used awk as -

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i "[o]cssd.bin" | awk '{ gsub("/ocssd.bin",""); print $NF}'
```

output:

```
$NF}
/opt/grid/12.1/bin
```

How to avoid "$NF}" ? I only need "/opt/grid/12.1/bin" ..!

Comment: That script WILL NOT output the string `NF}`. If you're getting that output then there's something wrong with some other part of your script that you aren't showing us yet. Also why do you do a case insensitive search in grep but then assume lower case in the awk sub() and what is the point of putting the `o` inside square brackets in the grep?

Comment: @EdMorton I don't know the answer to your other questions but the reason for the o in brackets is the prevent the grep itself from appearing as a match , people also pipe into `grep -v grep`

Comment: @123 thanks, I've never seen that approach before (or haven't noticed it).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ps -ef | grep -i "[o]cssd.bin" | awk '{ if(gsub("/ocssd.bin","")) print $NF}'
```

Comment: Since you have added `if(gsub("/ocssd.bin",""))`, isn't the `grep -i "[o]cssd.bin"` now superfluous?

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/[o]cssd.bin/{if(gsub("/ocssd.bin/",""))print $NF}'   # ignorecase

Comment: The `if` condition is true only if `gsub` makes a substitution (otherwise why do you have the `if` condition there at all?).  If so, then isn't the condition `/[o]cssd.bin/` superfluous?

Comment: The question and script in it make no sense. The OP is using inconsistent and bizarre language constructs and asking us to help him solve a problem that cannot occur. Given that - anything might be the right (or wrong) answer :-).